# Can Android Auto app connect to car dashboard device running Android 4.4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, android-auto

Does the [Android Auto app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.projection.gearhead&hl=en) require Android 5 on the car dashboard that it is streaming data to?

(Phone has Android 5)

Comment: Added link to Google Auto app

Comment: Do you have Android Auto setup on your car? It requires an Android phone running Lollipop version.

Comment: I don't have Android Auto, but can you see the Android version on your dashboard? AFAIK, there's only 1 version, which is called Android Auto itself.

Comment: I don't have AA yet, that's why I am asking. Want to buy a Kia car dashboard but the one I have in mind is Android 4.4 and I am unsure if the app from my 5.0 phone will connect at all :/

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this tweet from Android](https://twitter.com/Android/status/578603596926693377),

> Get #AndroidAuto today w/ Pioneer products & an Android 5.0+ device; now available in US, UK & AU. More partners coming soon.

So you'll need three things,

1. Android Auto compatible head unit.

   <sub>For example, the  [Pioneer AVIC-8100NEX Navigation receiver](http://www.crutchfield.com/p_1308100NEX/Pioneer-AVIC-8100NEX.html?tp=20212) head unit</sub>
2. An Android phone running Lollipop or higher versions.
3. Also, you need a compatible cable to connect the head unit to your Android smartphone.

> You'll also need a compatible microUSB cable such as the [Pioneer
> CD-MU200 cable](http://www.crutchfield.com/p_130CDMU200/Pioneer-CD-MU200.html) (or a similar microUSB-to-USB cable) to connect the
> phone to the receiver.

Comment: Which Android version is the Pioneer unit you linked to running? Can you link to a head unit for Kia Soul?

Comment: There has been no mention of that in the Details section. :/ You could buy an android-auto supported head unit and start using the AA feature. After you connect your mobile you'll be seeing the Lollipop style user interface even if your dashboard has Kitkat. ;)

Comment: Google recommends to contact your car manufacturer for Android Auto support. Read more on http://www.android.com/auto/

Comment: I did that. No response yet.